# SQL SERVER SELECT sum values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Problem is when I try get sum values from 2 different tables, but using condition from table 3 result are corrupted by wrong sum result . So I tried `Select sum() as t1 (select sum()...)` as `t2` and I want to sum `t1` and `t2`, in this way `t1` and `t2` result are correct
so there are code

```
SELECT
  SUM(daa.[price]) AS t1,
  (
      SELECT SUM(dap.[price]) AS suma
      FROM fydtr.dbo.[sales] AS dap,
           [fydtr].[dbo].[work info] AS di
      WHERE YEAR(di.[end of work datetime]) = 2013
          AND MONTH(di.[end of work datetime]) = 12
          AND di.[state] = 'e'
          AND di.[reg. nr.] = dap.[reg. nr.]
  ) AS t2
FROM [fydtr].[dbo].[work sale] AS daa,
     fydtr.dbo.[work info] AS dbi
WHERE YEAR(dbi.[end of work datetime]) = 2013
    AND MONTH(dbi.[end of work datetime]) = 12
    AND dbi.[state] = 'e'
    AND dbi.[reg. nr.] = daa.[reg. nr.]
```

It gives result

> t1 340
>   t2 509

And I need sum these and get 849 as t3.

Comment: [why][have][you][used][square][brackets][everywhere], [when][you][don't][need][to]?

Comment: [because] [when] [you] [save] [the] [tables] [path] [you] [can] [save] [script] [file] [and] [open] [for] [editing] [without] [errors] [that tables can't be found]

Comment: So what? Readability trumps convenience. Add something to the script that changes to the right database first if it's a problem. Don't pollute code with unnecessary characters, and if it ain't busted don't fix it. And btw, I would summarily dismiss anyone who put a space in a column/table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this.

```
select t1, t2, t1 + t2 t3
from (
the query from your question
) temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear, due to missing input data. But I assume you're searching for something like this:

```
select sum(sale.pice) as t1
    , sum(sales.price) as t2
    , sum(sales.price) + sum(sale.price) as t3
    from [work info] as info
        left outer join [work sale] as sale on (info.state = 'e' and info.[reg. nr.] = sale.[reg. nr.])
        left outer join [work sales] as sales on (info.state = 'e' and info.[reg. nr.] = sales.[reg. nr.])
    where year(info.[end of work datetime]) = 2013
        and month(info.[end of work datetime]) = 12
```

This depends on the relations between your tables, e.g. in my example, I'm assuming that there's only one entry per [reg. nr.] in all tables. Otherwise you could use "window functions", or UNIONS or CTE's (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). You might need to supply more context to get the answer you're searching for.

My given query is probably a little bit cleaner than your query. If that's not an issue, or if my assumption is wrong, then Dan Bracuk's answer helps you out.

And you should probably look at the column names, too. They're a little bit too complex in my opinion  :)